# Firefox is not loading the url

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

b=Watir::Browser.new 

b.goto 'www.google.com'
```

I am writing the above code to open the google.com in firefox, but the problem is, control is not leaving the second line even after opening the firefox browser and later it throws the given below error, Can anyone suggest me how to overcome this problem?

```
/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:90:in `connect_until_stable': unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
```

Comment: That error indicates webdriver was unable to connect to the browser.   Most typically that is caused when you get a new version of firefox auto-downloaded, but have not updated your webdriver gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pops up occasionally and it seems like one of the best options to start with is updating the selenium-webdriver gem. That did the trick for me.

```
gem update selenium-webdriver
```

I currently run with selenium-webdriver (2.53.4) with no issues.